# Ways to install programs in large clusters

Tags: nfs, cluster, mpi

For my internship I am currently setting up a cluster of laptops to run CFD applications using OpenFOAM. So far I've set it up installing SSH-client and NFS on both master and nodes. I've tested both ssh and my shared folder, and both works fine.

I would however like to be able to install and modify programs on the master only, and let the nodes use the programs from there.

I just finished installing both OpenMPI and OpenFOAM on the masters shared folder and edited the paths in the masters .bashrc script accordingly.

1. Does this seem like a feasible way to solve it? I feel like installing OpenMPI this way was a bold move.
2. Do I need to modify the .bashrc script on each of the nodes to make this work properly?
3. Will installing programs on the shared folder extend the computational time compared to installing both OpenMPI and OpenFOAM on each node?
4. Alternative ideas of ways to quickly set up a large cluster without too much work on each node would be greatly appreciated.

And no, I can't use Rocks clustering since the cluster I'm building consists of laptops with only 1 Ethernet port each. Is there any good alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to installing the software on the clients (laptops) and not only on the master, there are some IT automation solutions you could try.

To quickly install software on a wide range of machines, you can use [Ansibe](https://www.ansible.com/) ([here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-ansible-playbooks-to-automate-system-configuration-on-ubuntu) is a tutorial). As you have already set up SSH, this should be relatively easy. A great advantage of this approach is that you don't have to log in to every client; you can do all the work from one system.

You could also try [Puppet](https://puppet.com/), which is a configuration management tool (see [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorial_series/how-to-use-puppet-to-manage-your-servers-2) for a tutorial). This will help you ensure that all configuration settings are shared between machines. Note that Puppet is not that easy to set up and might be overkill for this case.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, however,  I am trying to stick with open source soltuions.  Running Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Both are open source (I realize the website would suggest otherwise) and are in the Ubuntu/Debian repositories.